# How to solve polynomial rational relations for $y$ (e.g $\sqrt{4-3y-y^2} = x(y+4)$)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From time to time, I struggle to solve polynomial relations for $y$.

A trivial example is :

$$ \frac{y}{x} = x \iff y = x^2$$

Easy.

---

But consider this relation:

$$ \sqrt{4-3y-y^2} = x(y+4)$$

No matter how much I mess around it, seems impossible to bring it in $y = f(x)$ form.

- $  \frac{\sqrt{4-3y-y^2}}{(y+4)}= x  $
- $ 4 - 3y - y^2 = x^2(y^2 + 8y + 16) \iff (x^2-1)y^2+y(-8x-3)+4(1-4x) = 0$

---

Is there a trivial methodology that I am missing or is it indeed impossible to inverse some relations?

Comment: Quadratic formula

Comment: Um..probably gonna work if you have a pair of equations.

Comment: @SameerBaheti How would I use quadatic formula here?

Comment: Treat the last equation as a quadratic in $y$.

Comment: Note that $4 - 3y - y^2 = (y+4)(1-y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{4-3y-y^2} &= x(y+4)\\
\sqrt{(1-y)(y+4)} &= x(y+4)\Rightarrow y\in[-4,1],x\in[0,+\infty)\\
\sqrt{y+4}\left(\sqrt{1-y}-x\sqrt{y+4}\right) &=0\Rightarrow \boxed{y=-4}\\
\sqrt{1-y}&=x\sqrt{y+4}\\
\sqrt{\frac{5}{y+4}-1}&=x\\
\boxed{y=\frac5{x^2+1}-4}\in(-4,1]\,\forall\,x\in[0,+\infty) 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

For $-4<y\le 1, x>0$
We have $$\sqrt{(y+4)(1-y)}=x (y+4) \implies (1-y)(y+4)=x^2(y+4)^2 \implies \frac{1-y}{y+4}=x^2$$
$$\implies y(x)=\frac{1-4x^2}{1+x^2}.$$
See the graph of $y(x)$ below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$4-3y-y^2=\dfrac{25-(2y+3)^2}4$$

needs to be perfect square of a rational number

Comment: How does this help with the problem?

Comment: @Veriun, $$x=\dfrac{\sqrt{4-3y-y^2}}{y+4}$$ right? So,$y$ only needs to satisfy the condition apart from $y+4\ne0$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sqrt{4-3y-y^2} = x(y+4)$$
$$  {4-3y-y^2} = x^2(y+4)^2$$
$${ y^2+3y-4} = -x^2(y+4)^2$$
$$(y+4)(y-1) = -x^2(y+4)^2$$
$$\frac{y-1}{y+4} = -x^2$$
$$\frac{1-y}{y+4} =  x^2$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{1-y}{y+4}} = x$$
$$ \frac{1-y}{y+4}  = x^2$$
$$1-y = x^2y + 4x^2$$
$$1-y  = x^2y + 4x^2$$
$$-y = x^2y + 4x^2-1$$
$$y = 1-x^2y - 4x^2 $$
$$y + x^2y = 1-4x^2$$
$$y(1+x^2) = 1-4x^2$$
$$y = \frac{1-4x^2}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Thanks Tim but I am trying to solve for $y$ not $x$!